# Undo a sort action in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, sorting, undo

Notepad++ (7.5.6) (32 bit) will sort all lines in a document using Ctrl-Z. If that is used accidentally, how do you undo the sort?

Comment: "Notepad++ (7.5.6) (32 bit) will sort all lines in a document using Ctrl-Z" No it won't. Ctrl-Z is Undo. You have misconfigured your version of Notepad++

Answer (score 1):

Sort command, e.g. done via TextFX plugin can be undone normally, I tested it right now.

You have these options:

- Determine which plugin does the sorting in your case and consider uninstalling it.
- Or just remove the keyboard shortcut from that sort action using **Settings** > **Shortcut Mapper**.
- Or alter keyboard shortcut for sorting to something less easy to press,
  e.g. change it from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (which is NOT a default sorting shortcut, btw.) to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> etc.